# How to uninstall a .deb installed with dpkg?

Tags: dpkg

I installed [Unified Remote](https://www.unifiedremote.com/) using `dpkg`:

```
dpkg -i urserver.deb
```

How do I uninstall it so I can reinstall from scratch?

Answer (score 251, accepted):

First of all you should check if this package is correctly installed in your system and being listed by `dpkg` tool:

`dpkg -l '*urserver*'`

It should have an option `ii` in the first column of the output - that means 'installed ok installed'.

If you'd like to remove the package itself (without the configuration files), you'll have to run:

`dpkg -r urserver`

If you'd like to delete (purge) the package completely (with configuration files), you'll have to run:

`dpkg -P urserver`

You may check if the package has been removed successfully - simply run again:

`dpkg -l urserver`

If the package has been removed without configuration files, you'll see the `rc` status near the package name, otherwise, if you have purged the package completely, the output will be empty.

Comment: Just a note that you have to use the package name, not the name of the installed software. Example: `dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb` installs `google-chrome`, but to remove you must use `dpkg -i google-chrome-stable`, _not_ `dpkg -i google-chrome`, _neither_  `dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb`.

Comment: Good note on the package name.  For instance : dpkg -l '*hddtemp*' returns:
||/ Name           Version       Architecture Description
+++-==============-=============-============-=========================================
ii  hddtemp        0.3-beta15-53 amd64        hard drive temperature monitoring utility

The 'name' column is what you need

Answer (score 23):

I figured it out:

```
dpkg -r urserver
```

Comment: If you want to remove the configuration files too then `dpkg -P ursserver`