# How do I tell aptitude that a package was installed manually?

Tags: debian, package-management, ffmpeg, aptitude

I installed a package (don't remember which one but that shouldn't be too important) and needed "the real" `ffmpeg` so I purged the debian package for `ffmpeg` and installed the other version manually.

The problem is that I now can't install or update any packages without `aptitude` telling me that `xyz package` requires `ffmpeg` which is not being installed. However, since the package is installed all the programs that depend on it work just fine. I don't want to overwrite the version I have with the repository version, I just want to tell `aptitude` that ffmpeg really is installed.

I've tried `apt-mark` but because aptitude doesn't think it's installed it won't mark it manual.

As requested `apt-cache policy ffmpeg` shows:

```
ffmpeg:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 7:3.2.10-1~deb9u1~bpo8+1
  Version table:
     10:2.6.9-dmo1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     7:3.2.10-1~deb9u1~bpo8+1 0
        100 http://http.debian.net/debian/ jessie-backports/main amd64 Packages
```

I'm still very much interested in a solution but I decided that I would just install the repository version and then reinstall the version I want. Aptitude did "install" ffmpeg but it didn't overwrite my current version (maybe it put it in a different spot or maybe it saw a "newer" version).

Comment: Can't you install it with a non-official repository?

Comment: Maybe but that's a separate thing. I installed it with `dpkg` but for whatever reason it's not being seen.

Comment: Same as localinstall on yum?

Comment: What does `apt-cache policy ffmpeg` output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## It is [not recommended](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch02.en.html#_basic_precautions) to install random packages with dpkg.

## Read the whole answer before taking any action

`Apt` is having an issue because it has not associated with your install of `ffmpeg`. As far as it is concerned you do not have `ffmpeg` installed and is giving you the above error because of this. Your output of `apt-cache policy ffmpeg` proves this. I am not aware of methods to associate a random `.deb` file with `apt` unless your package sets up `apt` during its install process. If someone can correct me about this, I would greatly appreciated it. If you need a package that is not available in you current repositories, you can, *at your own discretion*, add testing/unstable/backports/whatever repository to your sources.list that has the package you are looking for and use the package manager.

## I do not recommend you use an unofficial Debian repo.

Look up the available versions of `ffmpeg` [here](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=sourcenames&keywords=ffmpeg). If the version you want is in a repo other than stable you should then add it to your sources.list. If you [set up "Apt Pinning"](https://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences) you can manage multiple releases of Debian with little overhead. To fix your installation of `ffmpeg` start by removing your current instance so we can start from scratch.

```
apt-get purge ffmpeg
dpkg --purge ffmpeg
dpkg -l | ffmpeg
```

This purges `ffmpeg` and then looks to see if it is installed. You should be looking for an `rc` status as [per this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/195794/how-to-uninstall-a-deb-installed-with-dpkg). You can then follow the guide in [the wiki about apt pinning](https://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences) to add testing and unstable repos. Do not forget to create the files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` for each repo you plan on using, and a corresponding `/etc/apt/preferences.d/` file. Once you have created the proper files to get set up with apt pinning you can then simply run:

```
apt-get install ffmpeg/unstable
```

To install `ffmpeg` from the unstable repo. You can substitute unstable with whatever repo your desired package is from if you set up apt pinning.

## However if you absolutely must use an unofficial Debian repo

[Here is a guide to add a third-party repo](http://www.deb-multimedia.org/) that contains the `ffmpeg` package you a probably looking for. If you decide to go with apt pinning you will need to create the repo (`/etc/apt/sources.list.d/deb-multimedia.list`) and preferences (`/etc/apt/preferences.d/deb-multimedia.preferences`) instead. Complete the following steps after purging `ffmpeg` in the manner described previously.

```
nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Add this line:

```
deb http://www.deb-multimedia.org stretch main non-free
```

Save and exit. Now follow these steps:

> ```
> apt-get update
> ```
>
> The “-oAcquire::AllowInsecureRepositories=true” option is mandatory since Buster and thus also needed for unstable.
>
> ```
> apt-get update -oAcquire::AllowInsecureRepositories=true
>
> apt-get install deb-multimedia-keyring -oAcquire::AllowInsecureRepositories=true
> ```
>
> Since Squeeze you can install this package with apt-get. Simply press y when the package ask what to do (don't press return).
>
> If apt-get can not find the new key, do that :
>
> ```
> wget http://www.deb-multimedia.org/pool/main/d/deb-multimedia-keyring/deb-multimedia-keyring_2016.8.1_all.deb
> sudo dpkg -i deb-multimedia-keyring_2016.8.1_all.deb
> ```
>
> You can verify the package integrity with:
>
> ```
> sha256sum deb-multimedia-keyring_2016.8.1_all.deb
> 9faa6f6cba80aeb69c9bac139b74a3d61596d4486e2458c2c65efe9e21ff3c7d deb-multimedia-keyring_2016.8.1_all.deb
> ```
>
> Final and mandatory step.
>
> An `apt-get update` and `apt-get dist-upgrade` to install all packages related to ffmpeg.

After that you can run `apt-get install ffmpeg` and you should have the correct package.

## Conclusion

I understand this covers a lot but I wanted to be comprehensive. My personal philosophy with administrating Debian is to not stray from stable if possible, not stray from official repos with properly set up apt pinning according [to the Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences), and to carefully limiting and managing anything from a `.deb` or installed from source. If you can help prevent there from being conflicts between versioning of packages/libraries by having everything you possibly can be managed by `apt` you should be safe.

Sorry if this is too long winded or not what you needed I just wanted to make sure I covered all the bases. Best of Luck!

Comment: The above answer references a command `apt-aget` that I cannot find anywhere.  Is that a typo?

Comment: @Digger yes that would be a typo from my source deb-multimedia.org. I can edit it out.